# How to serialize a C# DateTime as a Javascript Date using Web API

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

In MVC, you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Json(new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Parse("19/02/2017") }, 
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the returned value is `["\/Date(1487458800000)\/"]`, which is a Javascript Date object.

However, using WebAPI like this:

```
public IEnumerable<DateTime> Get()
{
    return new List<DateTime> { DateTime.Parse("19/02/2017") };
}
```

The returned value is `<dateTime>2017-02-19T00:00:00</dateTime>`

Is there any way that I can serialize a DateTime as a Javascript Date object using WebApi?

Comment: Hi... do you just need the output to be 1487458800000.. I've found a method that uses date subtraction to calculate the Java date based upon the milliseconds elapsed since 1970

Comment: I need the object, because I want to bind it to an input datetime-local using Angular. And according to the documentation: "The model must always be a Date object"

Comment: Martin - Could you create the date objects in script when they are passed in?  var date = new Date(1487458800000);

Comment: The date is inside another object, which is inside a list of thousands. I rather not to convert every date. I know there are ways to convert it from string or ticks, but I'm looking for a way to get this simple task during serialization. MVC does, why Web API not?

Comment: Maybe you'll need to implement a custom media type formatter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145097/controlling-serialization-in-web-api-apicontroller

Comment: It seems too complex for a simple date serialization. There must be other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your `Accept` header on your request to `application/json` you get:

```
["2017-06-09T08:14:13.7729697-03:00"]
```

Try with a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

In angular, you can do something like:

```
var config = { headers:  {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
};

$http.get("/api/values", config);
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more how to change that header, please. I'm using Angular's $http.get to do the request.

Comment: It's kinda hard using a browser. IE defaults to JSON, but it downloads the file. FF and Chrome defaults to XML. Get Postman, then on `Headers` tab add a key `Accept` and a value `application/json`. Change it to `application/xml` and see how the output changes.

Comment: Nevermind, that was a stupid question. In Angular you can do it with `headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }`

Comment: Updated the answer with an `angular` example.

Comment: It does not work. Now in Postman I get this: `[
  "2017-02-19T00:00:00"
]`. I need the Date object.

Comment: Here you may find some useful info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249052/binding-a-date-in-angularjs-using-webapi-and-the-bootstrap-date-picker

Comment: Sorry, but is not useful. They are binding the date to a Bootstrap datepicker, which accepts dates in string format. That's not the case with datetime-local, which, according to the documentation: "The model must always be a Date object"

Answer (score 0):

You can use that format with JavaScript though:

```
var myDate = new Date("2017-02-19T00:00:00");
```

Comment: I know. This is not an answer to my question. I dont want to parse the date from a string, I want to convert directly from DateTime.